# How to change to animation blocks?

Tags: ios, animation

I want to change below code using blocks.
How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
-(void) move:(CGPoint) point
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:CFBridgingRetain(value)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:viewController];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stop:finished:context:)];
    view.center = view.center + point;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)stop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void  *)context 
{
     NSNumber *value = (NSNumber *)CFBridgingRelease(context);
    // something        
}
```

Comment: It depends on what `stop:finished:context:` does. Please post that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Init value variable here
NSNumber *value = @1;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    CGPoint center = view.center;
    center.x += point.x;
    center.y += point.y;
    view.center = center;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Access value after animation completion
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
}];
```